# How to make it clear that a game is in Beta?

Tags: user-experience, playtesting, beta

I develop games on [ROBLOX](http://www.roblox.com/) which is a site full of user-generated games that are typically free for other users to enjoy. Many users have studios in which they have a consistent set of playtesters, but I am the only developer in the case of my project. Nonetheless, I still have the need to test my game at times, so I recruit random people from the forums of the site (specifically the site's "Scripters forum"). While recruiting from the forums is a reliable and quick way to get players, it may be hard for them to get over the fact that the game is meant to be unfinished.

ROBLOX has a like and dislike system, and during testing I have already received three likes and *one dislike*. The dislike concerns me because I feel that someone probably evaluated my game on the notion of "This game should be working for me, but it's not." when those problems are the purpose of why I recruit people to go to the game in the first place. Many users even absurdly evaluated the game on its artistic value  which I believe to be an afterthought in the game development process versus functionality which should be at its core.

**For the future, how do I make it clear that the current game should be evaluated for its functionality, and that in the beta phase, it may or may not work for all users?**

Side note: I do some preliminary testing before I recruit testers to the game, so it works at the very least on my device, but their own experience varies based upon their quality of connection and device.

Comment: It sounds to me like your game is in alpha, if that. Not beta. Alpha means the game has art and is basically complete with a few known bugs. Beta means it is, in your opinion, ready for release.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of ways to do that.

- Change the title so that it gently says **BETA**
- Put a nice popup or message at the very start saying that this isn't the final version and will be changed, or anything like that.
- Watermark a corner of the window with the message "beta version"